# Cucumber JVM - Unable to run scripts due to JVM Jar error

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to Run Cucumber scripts using Selenium webdriver integrated with Jenkins. But, I'm seeing the below error. I couldn't see JVM jar file in the mentioned path. Please suggest.

Failure to find info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:jar:1.2.4 in http://10.119.4.88:8080/archiva/repository/OB_Repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central-proxy has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: do you have cucumber properly defined in your pom? did you try to force update it?

Comment: Yes. I have defined properly. No I didn't force update.

Comment: Are you using maven's surefire plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
Failure to find info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:jar:1.2.4 in http://10.119.4.88:8080/archiva/repository/OB_Repo
```

Seems to suggest that you perhaps have a intranet level Maven repository (Something similar to repo1.maven.org) defined via one of the following means

1. In your **~/.m2/setings.xml** file under `<mirrors>` section
2. In your pom file/parent pom file under the tag `<repositories>`

And your Maven repository `http://10.119.4.88:8080` does not have the Cucumber jars available in it.

To fix this, you would need to remove the reference to your Maven repository `http://10.119.4.88:8080` (based on wherever its been defined) (or) work with your Maven repository managing team to get this sorted out.